# Errored Triggered Emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I configured a triggered email in marketing cloud. Due to an issue regarding ampscript, few emails failed. I was wondering if there was a way to retrieve these errored records of a triggered email?

Comment: what was the error you got?

Comment: The error is due to a wrong ampscript sintax code specifically a lookupDE function. I have already corrected this issue modifying it; however I would recover all the failed records written in the triggered DE in order to try to send again the email that these contacts didn't receive.

Answer (score 2):

In case you created a send logging data extension and activated logging for that triggered send, you can retrieve the failed sends using the triggered send's id.

**Further information on send logging:**

- [Send Logging](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/send_logging/)
- [Create a Email Send Logging Data Extension](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/send_logging/create_a_send_logging_data_extension/)
- [Enable Send Logging for a User-Initiated or Triggered Send](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/send_logging/enable_send_logging_for_a_user_initiated_or_triggered_send/)
- [Send Logging Best Practices and Tips](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/send_logging/send_logging_best_practices_and_tips/)